# How to encrypt with MCRYPT_ARCFOUR in WAMP?

Tags: php, cryptography, wamp, mcrypt

I'm trying to use ARCFOUR algorithm in my PHP code:

```
$td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_ARCFOUR, '', MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, '');
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv (mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td), MCRYPT_RAND);
mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, $iv);
$output = mcrypt_generic($td, $input);
mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
mcrypt_module_close($td);
```

and the problem is that the first line returns warning:

```
mcrypt_module_open(): Could not open encryption module
```

---

**My settings:**

- From php_info() output:

  command configure: ... "--with-mcrypt=static" ...

  If I'm correct it means I do not need a DLL for mcrypt extension.

  **Supported ciphers:** cast-128 gost rijndael-128 twofish arcfour cast-256 loki97 rijndael-192 saferplus wake blowfish-compat des rijndael-256 serpent xtea blowfish enigma rc2 tripledes
- PHP version 5.3.8
- Wamp 2.2a (32 bits)

Thank you for help!

Comment: Does `phpinfo()` have a *dedicated section* for mcrypt, or does it just include it in the configure line?  If there's no dedicated section for it, then the extension isn't properly loaded.

Comment: There's dedicated section. It contains supported ciphers that I added to my question above.

Comment: I was about to say "well, that explains it, there's no RC4 there," but it's sitting right where it should be between Twofish and CAST-256.  Your example code also fails for me.  5.3.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**As of PHP 5.3.6 and 5.4.0 RC6**, the `arcfour`, `wake` and `enigma` mcrypt ciphers *require the use of `stream` mode*.  They will not initialize any of the other modes, nor can any of the other ciphers use `stream` mode.

This *may* be true of earlier PHP versions as well.

Demo code, with the `@` present to silence the "can't open module" warning:

```
foreach(mcrypt_list_algorithms() as $alg) {
    printf("\n%20s:", $alg);
    foreach(mcrypt_list_modes() as $mode) {
        $mc = @mcrypt_module_open($alg, null, $mode, null);
        if(is_resource($mc)) echo "\t$mode";
        else echo "\t!!FAIL!!:$mode";
    }
}
echo "\n";
```

Demo output:

```
        cast-128:   cbc cfb ctr ecb ncfb    nofb    ofb !!FAIL!!:stream
            gost:   cbc cfb ctr ecb ncfb    nofb    ofb !!FAIL!!:stream
    rijndael-128:   cbc cfb ctr ecb ncfb    nofb    ofb !!FAIL!!:stream
         twofish:   cbc cfb ctr ecb ncfb    nofb    ofb !!FAIL!!:stream
         arcfour:   !!FAIL!!:cbc    !!FAIL!!:cfb    !!FAIL!!:ctr    !!FAIL!!:ecb    !!FAIL!!:ncfb   !!FAIL!!:nofb   !!FAIL!!:ofb    stream
        cast-256:   cbc cfb ctr ecb ncfb    nofb    ofb !!FAIL!!:stream
          loki97:   cbc cfb ctr ecb ncfb    nofb    ofb !!FAIL!!:stream
    rijndael-192:   cbc cfb ctr ecb ncfb    nofb    ofb !!FAIL!!:stream
       saferplus:   cbc cfb ctr ecb ncfb    nofb    ofb !!FAIL!!:stream
            wake:   !!FAIL!!:cbc    !!FAIL!!:cfb    !!FAIL!!:ctr    !!FAIL!!:ecb    !!FAIL!!:ncfb   !!FAIL!!:nofb   !!FAIL!!:ofb    stream
 blowfish-compat:   cbc cfb ctr ecb ncfb    nofb    ofb !!FAIL!!:stream
             des:   cbc cfb ctr ecb ncfb    nofb    ofb !!FAIL!!:stream
    rijndael-256:   cbc cfb ctr ecb ncfb    nofb    ofb !!FAIL!!:stream
         serpent:   cbc cfb ctr ecb ncfb    nofb    ofb !!FAIL!!:stream
            xtea:   cbc cfb ctr ecb ncfb    nofb    ofb !!FAIL!!:stream
        blowfish:   cbc cfb ctr ecb ncfb    nofb    ofb !!FAIL!!:stream
          enigma:   !!FAIL!!:cbc    !!FAIL!!:cfb    !!FAIL!!:ctr    !!FAIL!!:ecb    !!FAIL!!:ncfb   !!FAIL!!:nofb   !!FAIL!!:ofb    stream
             rc2:   cbc cfb ctr ecb ncfb    nofb    ofb !!FAIL!!:stream
       tripledes:   cbc cfb ctr ecb ncfb    nofb    ofb !!FAIL!!:stream
```

---

It looks like you (and I) are seeing [PHP bug 49311](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49311), which was closed after no feedback in 2009.  [RC4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4), [WAKE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAKE_%28cipher%29) and Enigma are broken.  Code to demonstrate the problem:

```
foreach(mcrypt_list_algorithms() as $algo) {
    echo $algo; 
    $td = mcrypt_module_open($algo, '', MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, '');
    echo "\n";
}
```

Output on my system, from the PHP interactive prompt:

```
cast-128
gost
rijndael-128
twofish
arcfourPHP Warning:  mcrypt_module_open(): Could not open encryption module in php shell code on line 1
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() php shell code:0
PHP   2. mcrypt_module_open() php shell code:1

cast-256
loki97
rijndael-192
saferplus
wakePHP Warning:  mcrypt_module_open(): Could not open encryption module in php shell code on line 1
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() php shell code:0
PHP   2. mcrypt_module_open() php shell code:1

blowfish-compat
des
rijndael-256
serpent
xtea
blowfish
enigmaPHP Warning:  mcrypt_module_open(): Could not open encryption module in php shell code on line 1
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() php shell code:0
PHP   2. mcrypt_module_open() php shell code:1

rc2
tripledes
```

Until (unless) they fix this bug or a workaround is found, you'll want to choose a different encryption algorithm.

Comment: I found the "PHP bug 49311" page too, but I hoped it would not be my case. Thank you for the test. RC6, IDEA and CRYPT are broken too (on my system). Actually, it doesn't even work on 5.3.8-pl0-gentoo.

Comment: Yeah, clearly it's a problem in general with the mcrypt extension and the person that replied to the bug didn't even bother with reproduction or troubleshooting.

Comment: I posted this question to the bugtracker. Hopefully, it will be fixed. But I need those algorithms right now so it's just bad luck.

Comment: @MartyIX: If you specifically need RC4, it shouldn't be too hard to implement it in PHP based on e.g. [the pseudocode on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4).  Or just use one of the existing implementations you can find by [Googling for "php rc4"](http://google.com/search?q=php+rc4).  It probably won't be very fast, but it should do the job.

Comment: http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ - I found this project and I'll test it tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

These three are stream cyphers. All other cyphers are block cyphers. They can't use the same modes as each other.

So just use MCRYPT_MODE_STREAM where you are using MCRYPT_MODE_CBC and you should be golden.

If not, use something like this:

```
/** Encrypts text with ARC4 algorithm. */
public static function encryptArc4($key, $data) {
    $iv = ""; // Empty init vector.
    return mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_ARCFOUR, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_STREAM, $iv);
}

/** Decrypts text with ARC4 algorithm. */
public static function decryptArc4($key, $data) {
    $iv = ""; // Empty init vector.
    return mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_ARCFOUR, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_STREAM, $iv);
}
```

Works for me.

Comment: Functions have param `$data` but are using `$text` in body?

Comment: @wqw Fixed, thanks! Also had an error on one of the comments.