# using mcrypt with enigma algorithm

Tags: php, mamp, mcrypt

i have the following example Code for using mcrypt with php:

```
/* Open the cipher */
$td = mcrypt_module_open('tripledes', '', 'ofb', '');

/* Create the IV and determine the keysize length, use MCRYPT_RAND
 * on Windows instead */
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td), MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM);
$ks = mcrypt_enc_get_key_size($td);

/* Create key */
$key = substr(md5('this is a very good key'), 0, $ks);

/* Intialize encryption */
mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, $iv);

/* Encrypt data */
$encrypted = mcrypt_generic($td, 'This is very important data');

/* Terminate encryption handler */
mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);

/* Initialize encryption module for decryption */
mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, $iv);

/* Decrypt encrypted string */
$decrypted = mdecrypt_generic($td, $encrypted);

/* Terminate decryption handle and close module */
mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
mcrypt_module_close($td);

/* Show string */
echo trim($decrypted) . "\n<br>";
```

This code is working fine, but I have to use "enigma" instead of tripledes.

If I'm changing the first line to:

```
mcrypt_module_open('enigma', '', 'ofb', '');
```

I get the following errors:

```
Warning: mcrypt_module_open(): Could not open encryption module in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/mcrypt.php on line 13
Warning: mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/mcrypt.php on line 17
Warning: mcrypt_create_iv(): Cannot create an IV with a size of less than 1 or greater than 2147483647 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/mcrypt.php on line 17
Warning: mcrypt_enc_get_key_size() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/mcrypt.php on line 18
Warning: mcrypt_generic_init() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/mcrypt.php on line 24
Warning: mcrypt_generic() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/mcrypt.php on line 27
Warning: mcrypt_generic_deinit() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/mcrypt.php on line 30
Warning: mcrypt_generic_init() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/mcrypt.php on line 33
Warning: mdecrypt_generic() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/mcrypt.php on line 36
Warning: mcrypt_generic_deinit() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/mcrypt.php on line 39
Warning: mcrypt_module_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/mcrypt.php on line 40
```

I don't know why this happens and how to fix it. If I'm checking the available modes with:

```
$modes = mcrypt_list_modes();

foreach ($modes as $mode) {
    echo "$mode <br />\n";
}
```

I get the following:

```
cbc
cfb
ctr
ecb
ncfb
nofb
ofb
stream
```

By checking the available algorithms:

```
$algorithms = mcrypt_list_algorithms("/usr/local/lib/libmcrypt");

foreach ($algorithms as $cipher) {
    echo "$cipher<br />\n";
}
```

I receive this output:

```
cast-128
gost
rijndael-128
twofish
arcfour
cast-256
loki97
rijndael-192
saferplus
wake
blowfish-compat
des
rijndael-256
serpent
xtea
blowfish
enigma
rc2
tripledes
```

I hope someone knows what's the problem and how to fix this. Thanks!

Comment: The answer to: [questions/8040901/how-to-encrypt-with-mcrypt-arcfour-in-wamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8040901/how-to-encrypt-with-mcrypt-arcfour-in-wamp) mentions 'stream' mode and may be useful.

Comment: @RyanVincent, it is working. Could you please suggest it as solution? :)

Comment: It nay be more appropriate for you to include the link in your question and include a comment about 'stream' mode. The linked question provides a complete explanation so my answer would add nothing of extra value..